# Notifications greyed out after waking up from sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, performance, notifications

I got a fairly new MacBook Pro and I am quite happy with it. The only thing that keeps happening all the time and frustrates me is that Notifications appear greyed and not responsive (when clicking on it etc.) after i wake the Mac up from sleep.
I use the MBP in Clamshell-Mode and hooked up to two external monitors and it does happen regularly but not every time after waking up.

Until now i keep using the terminal command

```
killall NotificationCenter
```

which does seem to help for some time.

Thank you all in advance and I hope there is a way to fix this.

Cheers!

- OS: MacOS Mojave 10.14.1
- Model: MacBook Pro 2018 15"

Comment: do you have the `Do not disturb` turned on ? and the `When display is sleeping` ?

Comment: No i have Do not disturb turned off

Comment: Has no one any idea how this issue could be fixed?

Comment: killall NotificationCenter is the best I've found too.  I've also added a shortcut to Terminal "knc" to make this faster since I have to run it multiple times a week, by adding this to the terminal config (in my case ~/.zshrc): `alias knc='killall NotificationCenter'`

Comment: Interesting enough, after several reboots and using my Macbook for a time now, the problem seemed to disappear at some point. It is working now properly. Unfortunately I am not able to tell you what fixed it...